# What does cocos2d-x 3.x Texture2D::TexParams corresponds to in cocos2d-js 3.x?

Tags: textures, cocos2d-js

I'm trying to work on a project using cocos2d-js 3.1, and I can't find the way to edit texture parameters like we do in cocos2d-x. (there doesn't seem to be anything about it in the documentation)

If in general you know how to fill up a layer or a sprite with a repeated texture in cocos2d-js, that would be super helpful.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

i find these in the source code CCTexture2d.h

```
    * @code 
* When this function bound into js or lua,the input parameter will be changed
* In js: var setBlendFunc(var arg1, var arg2, var arg3, var arg4)
* In lua: local setBlendFunc(local arg1, local arg2, local arg3, local arg4)
* @endcode
*/
void setTexParameters(const TexParams& texParams);
```

so ,perhaps setBlendFunc is what you need?